# Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, mariadb, ubuntu-20.04

[image]

I can't know what should I do..
I entered a command `service mysql restart` and error is occured..

What's the problem.. help me please!

Comment: Please paste here text, not images

Comment: I am so sorry... I couldn't solve the problem.
So I reinstalled mysql..
Of course I backed data up and restored suceesfully.
I will paste text next time..

Comment: Look at `journalctl -n 30 -u mariadb.service` too next time. The `systemctl` output here is limited until after it shutdown. Glad you got it working. Welcome to SO. There's also [DB SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) for pure DB questions.